# Is it possible to embed Spring's JsessionId into a JWT token?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In an application (which uses a third party identity provider for authentication) that I am building, I'm planning to use JWT tokens to encode information about the user and send it to the frontend. I also don't want to use a separate cookie for the session (the JsessionId cookie), and instead want to add the JsessionId inside the JWT token itself, and then check it in every request to see if the session is valid or not.

Which Spring security filter do I need to override for this? Are there any standard ways in which this can be accomplised.

Comment: So you want to use the token to save the session id??

Comment: @NatFar Yes I want to store the session id in the token.

Comment: I think that would depend on who's resolving your sessions - whether the server is providing the HttpSession, or if you're using Spring Session, or some other technology